# Могу ли я динамически добавлять объект в FormGroup

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4, angular5

У меня есть такой FormBuilder:

```
public categoryForm = this.fb.group({
categoryName: ['', Validators.required],
fields: this.fb.group({
  section: this.fb.group({
    title: [''],
    field:this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control('')
    ])
  })
 })
});
```

**Могу ли я динамически при нажатии на кнопку добавлять объект "section" ?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа :)](https://www.google.com/search?q=add+form+control+dynamically+angular&oq=add+form+control&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.2906j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @overthesanity уже сделал, https://stackblitz.com/edit/deep-nested-reactive-form?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts может кому-то пригодиться